# How to notify highlight bar about record changes?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

On my lightning record page i have a standard "Highlight Panel" component that displays some data in addition to some more components below (tab component with record detail component, etc.)

When I change some values using the standard detail page component, the corresponding values in the highlight bar get updated as well (e.g. when i change the oppty amount).

My question now is: What event to I need to fire in my custom lightning component (which is included in a another tab, next to the record details) to notify the highlight panel about record changes (happening through interaction with my component) without refreshing the entire view?

I cannot seem to find any applicable event in the documentation...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The **force:editRecord** will fire when you update the records from
>   the standard component and the handler will handle that event. Call
>   the required method from the handler. Add these two line in your custom component.

```
<aura:dependency resource="markup://force:editRecord" type="EVENT" />
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.doInit}" />
```

Comment: I don't think that'll help. I want to fire an event from my custom component, so another component (the standard highlight bar) reloads its data. force:editRecord opens the edit page - i don't want that. See: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_editRecord.htm